# How do I specify a table with 2 foreign keys in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I have a legacy database where I the relationships between 2 entities are defined in a different table. How do I create that relationship in rails?

The basic relationship I want to present is:

---Admins:

```
First_name
Last_name
id
```

---Sites:

```
id
subject
```

---Admin_Sites

```
 id
 teacher_id
 class_id
```

I know in rails I would just use belongs_to: and has_many: but if I have a (constantly updated) teach_class table, I need to somehow specify that THAT's where rails need to look for the relationship of who is related to which class. I am at a loss how I can specify this. Is it possible to somehow specify :foreign_key as "teach_class.teacher_id" in classes model?

Comment: **Calling anything in Ruby `Classes` or `Class` is treading a very fine line. Don't do this!!**

Comment: this is just to illustrate - my actual classes are sites and admins, for whatever reason i thought it'd be faster to explain it teacher/class

Comment: Please do not use fake values, as they can be confusing or misleading. Sometimes both.

Comment: I didn't use any values at all - these are labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this blog for has_many :through relationship - http://ruby-on-rails-dipak-panchal.blogspot.in/2012/10/has-many-through-relationship.html

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_sites
  has_many :sites, :through => :admin_sites
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_sites
  has_many :admins, :through => :admin_sites
end

class AdminSites < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
  belongs_to :site
end
```

Comment: D'oh this is what I should have realized. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Teacher Model you would have

```
has_many :teach_classes
has_many :classes, :through => :teach_classes
```